# Angular Translate - how to retrieve dynamic variable list

Tags: angularjs, translate

I have this in the translation json file:

```
{ 
  "test_key" : "Var1: {{var1}} Var2: {{var2}} Var3: {{var3}}" 
}
```

For this to work, I need to provide var1, var2, and var 3. For example:

```
$translate('test_key', { var1: 1, var2: 2, var3: 3 });
```

The issue now is that var1, var2, var3 could be any dynamic variables. What I need now is to get all the list of dynamic variables so I can provide whatever values it may need.

Ideally, this is the goal I am trying to achieve (pseudo code)

```
var dynamicVars = getDynamicVarList(); // I need this, but how? 
dynamicVars.forEach(function (key) {
    switch (key) {
        case "var1":
            return 1;

        case "var2":
            return 2;

        case "var3":
            return 3;

        default:
            return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is **Pascal Precht translate**, then you set **JSON** file in module options, before application init. It's rather not possible with standard mechanisms. It offer **JSON**, but when it is loaded, then it's hard to change something, without changing source code of **angular translate** module. 
If the reason you want this is to have many languages, then you can set many languages codes in **$translate**. 
Another solution is to load JSON from server, which performs operations on var1, var2, var3 and hence returns static json, but you can do **$http** calls with commands to change variables in switch statement. 
It looks somehow linguistic approach, **Java** is good for this. **Grails** may be fine framework for returning REST services.

Comment: Yes, loading JSON from server is one option. But Angular-translate itself already does that so the additional retrieval of json seems redundant. The setback in angular-translate is that when using dynamic variables, you will have to know the variables ahead of time to know which values to provide. This is the main problem we are encountering as we would want to retrieve the dynamic vars list first, then provide the values.

Comment: I think that you will have to change module or add this feature in module github page.

Answer (score 0):

Again, to restate the problem, the issue is that you do not know ahead of time which dynamic variables are to be used.

I solved the issue by using a customer interpolator.

So when you do

> {{'testkey'|translate}}

and your lang.json has:

> "testkey" :"this is number {{variable1}}"

It will get resolved to

> this is number 1

Code:

```
app.factory('customTranslateInterpolator',
            ["$interpolate",

            function ($interpolate) {
                var $locale;
                var customTranslateInterpolator = {};

                /**
                 * This will be your custom dynamic vars resolution method
                 */
                var resolveExpressions = function (expressions) {
                    var values = {};
                    expressions.forEach(function (key) {
                        values[key] = resolveVariable(key);
                    });
                    return values;
                }

                /**
                 * The actual method for key:value mapping
                 */
                var resolveVariable = function(key) {
                    var retVal;

                    switch (key) {
                        case "variable1":
                            retVal = 1;
                            break;

                        default:
                            retVal = "";
                    }

                    return retVal;
                }

                customTranslateInterpolator.setLocale = function (locale) {
                    $locale = locale;
                }
                customTranslateInterpolator.getInterpolationIdentifier = function () {
                    return 'custom';
                },

                /**
                 * Custom interpolate
                 * interpolateParams will overwrite resolve expressions. This will allow developers
                 * to pass values to the translate directives or by using $translate service.
                 * 
                 * @param {string} string the string retrieved from the language json file
                 * @param {object} interpolateParams the {key:value} object passed to the angular-translate features.
                 */
                customTranslateInterpolator.interpolate = function (string, interpolateParams) {
                    var result;
                    interpolateParams = interpolateParams || {
                    };

                    // Retrieve expressions and resolve them
                    var interpolatedString = $interpolate(string);
                    var resolvedExpressions = resolveExpressions(interpolatedString.expressions);

                    // Merge interpolateParams onto resolvedExpressions so that interpolateParams overwrites resolvedExpressions
                    angular.extend(resolvedExpressions, interpolateParams);

                    result = interpolatedString(resolvedExpressions);
                    return result;
                }
                return customTranslateInterpolator;
            }]);
```

make sure you let angular-translate know you are using a custom interpolator

> $translateProvider.useInterpolation('customTranslateInterpolator');

Note that you can still provide your own translate-values, and this will override whatever you have in resolveVariable()

So if you do

> {{'testkey' | translate:"{variable1:'2'}"}}

It will resolve to

> this is number 2

Hope this helps others.

-Lucky M.